# Trying to make automatic compilation of an Unity Engine project on Ubuntu

Tags: unity-game-engine, gitlab-ci

I'm working on a project an Unity Engine project which is in version 2017.4.36f1. I would like to automatise the build of this project on the Gitlab with the online runners.

So I made a `.gitlab-ci.yml` to make a custom pipeline. In this pipeline I use the image ubuntu:16.04.

I download Unity using `wget -nv https://beta.unity3d.com/download/c663def8414c/UnitySetup-2017.4.36f1`

I install it with `echo y | xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args='-screen 0 640x480x24' ./UnitySetup --unattended --install-location=Unity --verbose --download-location=/tmp/unity --components=Unity, Windows`

I activate the licence for this computer and then I build for Windows 64 with the command line

```
${UNITY_EXECUTABLE:-xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args='-screen 0 640x480x24' $HOME/Unity/Editor/Unity} \
  -projectPath $(pwd)/ClientUnity/MK_Unity3D \
  -quit \
  -batchmode \
  -buildTarget StandaloneWindows64 \
  -customBuildTarget StandaloneWindows64 \
  -customBuildPath BuildStandaloneWindows64 \
  -executeMethod BuildCommand.PerformBuild \
  -logFile /dev/stdout
```

There is no error during the build but at the end It cannot found the Windows standalone Package and so it stops.

Here is the message given at the end of the build :

```
Initializing Unity.PackageManager (PackageManager) v2017.4.36 for Unity v2017.4.36f1
Registering platform support modules:
Registered platform support modules in: 0.1674048s.
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Native extension for LinuxStandalone target not found
```

Comment: `Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found` probably already says it all. It didn't even start a build since it couldn't switch to your target platform. The log you see from before is probably only starting up Unity itself

Comment: Doing this on Linux is always a bit a hickup .. best would actually be you do your builds on a windows PC/server.

Comment: I thought that at the setup of Unity adding the component windows allows to build StandaloneWindows. I will try to build it with a windows image.